# Interpretation of Halstead-Reitan Impairment Index Parameter

Tags: cognitive-psychology, cognitive-neuroscience, brain-injury

How does one best interpret the Halstead-Reitan Index ranging from 0.0 to 1 ? How closely is this assessment of neurocognition subsequent to injury correlated to structural arrangement of the brain per medical imaging.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Cognitive Science :) Keep in mind that the questions here should apply to a broader public and also we cannot and don't want to provide a diagnosis for people. So I would suggest, that you edit your question. A usual approach to questions like yours is that you have a first paragraph that describes your personal situation, thereby motivating the question. And in a second paragraph you frame the question in a general manner. Let us know if you need help with editing it :)

Comment: Thank you. Have no fear, I am in no need of additional diagnosis what with the team of 20 specialists hovering. Just curious about a more user friendly understanding of the Halstead-Reitan index as this is outside the scope of my professional sphere.